# Including a generic class in Unity App.Config file

Tags: c#, generics, app-config, unity-container

I have a class of type `ISimpleCache<IBrokeredDataObject>` that I want to add as a type alias (then a type) in the App.Config file

the line

```
<typeAlias alias="ISimpleCacheOfIBrokeredDataObject" type="MyApplication.ISimpleCache<IBrokeredDataObject>, MyApplication" />
```

is obviously wrong due to the <>, however I'm not convinced escaping them;

```
<typeAlias alias="ISimpleCacheOfIBrokeredDataObject" type="MyApplication.ISimpleCache&lt;IBrokeredDataObject&gt;, MyApplication" />
```

is correct either.

I am currently ripping my code apart to use Unity, so am too far from a compilable code base to test this quickly, and was hoping to get some confirmation here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/07/25/working-with-generic-types-in-unity-configuration-section.aspx) blog post:

> In order to write a generic type, use the `` ` `` sign followed by the number of generic types that the interface/class receives.

And a comment in the same page said:

> In order to use a constant type in the generic you need to use brackets (`[[ ]]`).

So I guess your configuration file should contain something like this:

```
<typeAlias alias="ISimpleCacheOfIBrokeredDataObject"
   type="MyApplication.ISimpleCache`1[[MyApplication.IBrokeredDataObject, MyApplication]], MyApplication" />
```

Note the use of the "grave accent" or "backquote" character (`` ` ``), not the normal single quote (`'`).

Comment: It's worth adding that it must be ` NOT ' (subtle but important difference)

Answer (score 14):

I would have rather commented on the answer above, but my score isn't high enough.

The syntax is documented for the Type.GetType Method (string) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

There are a bunch of examples, a few of which I pasted below.

**A generic type with one type argument**

```
Type.GetType("MyGenericType`1[MyType]")
```

**A generic type with two type arguments**

```
Type.GetType("MyGenericType`2[MyType,AnotherType]")
```

**A generic type with two assembly-qualified type arguments**

```
Type.GetType("MyGenericType`2[[MyType,MyAssembly],[AnotherType,AnotherAssembly]]")
```

**An assembly-qualified generic type with an assembly-qualified type argument**

```
Type.GetType("MyGenericType`1[[MyType,MyAssembly]],MyGenericTypeAssembly")
```

**A generic type whose type argument is a generic type with two type arguments**

```
Type.GetType("MyGenericType`1[AnotherGenericType`2[MyType,AnotherType]]")
```

Comment: How can you best figure out the type and assembly value?  I'm trying to load some reallly simple things like an int or Guid and getting really frustrated because Unity isn't liking any of it and the exception messages are only slightlyl helpful.  For example, this doesn't work:
    <alias alias="IRepoGeneric" type="ConfigFile4MultipleTemplateTypes.IRepoGeneric`2[[ConfigFile4MultipleTemplateTypes.Foo,ConfigFile4MultipleTemplateTypes],[System.Guid,mscorib.System]], ConfigFile4MultipleTemplateTypes" />

Answer (score 2):

And this is how you use a type that receives two generic types:

```
<section name="doubleFamilyConfig"
         type="ConfigTest.Configuration.FamilySection`2[
               [ConfigTest.Types.Child, ConfigTest],
               [ConfigTest.Types.Parent, ConfigTest]
               ],
               ConfigTest" />
```

You can use each type on a different line if you wish, so that it is easier to understand. Note that the first bracket must be right after the type (  FamilySection`2**[**  ).

Answer (score 1):

And this is strongly signed type as generic parameter.

```
<typeAlias alias="IPublisherOfXElement" type="MyLib.IX.IPublisher`1[[System.Xml.Linq.XElement, System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], MyLib.IX" />
```