# Generics in custom configuration sections

Tags: .net, configuration-files

I tried making a custom configuration class that went on like this:

```
WatcherServiceInfoSection<TWatcherServiceDetailElement>
```

where TWatcherServiceDetailElement is a `ConfigurationElement` inside it.

Now when I call the type in the `ConfigSections` area of AppConfig I get the error:

```
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for WatcherServiceInfo: 
Could not load type 'Library.Common.Utilities.ConfigurationHandler.WatcherServiceInfoSection<ASNDPService.Configuration.WatcherServiceDetailElement>' from assembly
```

Is what I'm doing possible? Can I have generic types in the type attribute for a custom section element?

**EDIT**

Additionally, how about `ConfigurationElementCollection` objects? Like in the above example, how could I do a

```
[ConfigurationProperty("WatcherServiceDetails", IsRequired = true, 
IsDefaultCollection = true)]
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(TWatcherServiceDetailElement), AddItemName = "WatcherServiceDetail")]
public WatcherServiceDetailCollection<TWatcherServiceDetailElement> WatcherServiceDetails
```

I'm aware that type parameters aren't allowed for attributes and that's what I want to know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify the full name of the type.

This includes the full name of the generic type followed by a <kbd>`</kbd> and the number of generic type parameters with the full names of the type parameters in <kbd>[...]</kbd>

e.g.

```
<component id="FooRetriever"
           service="Namespace.IRetrievable`2[[Namespace.Foo, Assembly],[System.String]], Assembly"
           type="Namespace.FooRetriever, Assembly"/>
```

I will try to whip up a more reasonable example.

see http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/castle-windsor-tips-specifying-generic-types-in-config-file/

also see [Including a generic class in Unity App.Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454726/including-a-generic-class-in-unity-app-config-file)